# Fire an event on button click - on a TI CC2541 Keyfob device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am new to BLE communication and as for now I am working on an android

 to communicate against the TI CC2541 keyfob device.

 My problem however is that I want to know when the user clicks on the Keyfob right side

 button (the one which is normally used to transmit a discovery signal) after I am connected to the device
I have used [Steven Rudenko's Github project](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleSensorTag) to understand the communication basics

But I CANT FIND NO WHERE (Not even on TI's official Documents) how I can tell (On the client side)
 If the right button is pressed.

Is it a service? do I have to register for some notification from the device?
In case someone have a general guidance I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I can think of three ways of doing this, with different advantages/costs.  One is to create a characteristic which you can subscribe to updates of.  Another would be to poll a characteristic.  And the last would be to create a beacon that advertises periodically, and change the advertisement payload based on the button state.

Comment: Hi Chris,
Thanks for your fast response - I havent thought about polling the device periodically but can I do that using the "out of the box" Ti keyfob - if so what service can I use? do you have some documents or a code exmaple I can look into?
Tnx again for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLE uses service-based architecture and can communicate using an attribute protocol (GATT Generic Attribute Profile).
Service is a collection of characteristics, where a characteristic is an attribute which you can read, write, register for notifications and more.

The keys on the keyfob are represented by a service and there is a characteristic that hold the status of the buttons.
I you should be able to register for notifications on this characteristic. (enable the Sensor for notification)

Checkout class [TiKeysSensor](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleSensorTag/blob/master/src/sample/ble/sensortag/sensor/TiKeysSensor.java) in [Steven Rudenko's project](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleSensorTag)

Comment: Thanks bro, I saw that project just couldn't exactly understand how can I register for that event, I managed to handle it eventually (a lot thanks to his example project) I have another question though will be glad if you'll have any lead - I am registering for the button press notification after I am connected to the GATT server by adding - <br>  TiKeysSensor senseor = new  TiKeysSensor() <br> bleService.enableSensor(sensor, true).
However that crashes when I run the application on a nullpointer excpetion, strange thing is whenever I am in debug mode that never happens (i.e. no null pointer)